# Relations between real and complex irreducible representations of a finite group with the same Frobenius-Schur indicator value

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to learn some representation theory of finite groups and am struggling with the relation between complex and real irreducible representations (irrep). By a complex (resp. real) irrep of a finite group $G$, I mean a homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$, where $V$ is a complex (resp. real) vector space. Here is a standard result:

Given a finite group $G$, if we choose to represent it in a complex vector space, then we know that any (unitary) complex irreducible representation (irrep) can be one of three types, depending on its Frobenius-Schur indictor $\nu$: 1) $\nu=1$: $\rho$ is isomorphic (through a similarity transformation) to a real-valued representation. 2) $\nu=0$: $\rho$ is not isomorphic to a its complex conjugate; 3) $\nu=-1$: $\rho$ is isomorphic to its complex conjugate, but not to a real-valued representation.

We also know that if we choose to represent $G$ in a real vector space, then the Frobenius-Schur indicator of any real irrep also takes $1$ (real type or absolutely irreducible), $0$ (complex type), or $-1$ (quarternion type).

My original question asked about the transformations from complex to real irrep of each type. It seems that for $\nu=1$ it is non-trivial to find a similarity transformation from the complex irrep to a real irrep. An earlier post in [How to find irreducible representation of a group from reducible one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/how-to-find-irreducible-representation-of-a-group-from-reducible-one) mentioned some algorithms for computing the character table and suggested that computation over finite fields is usually easier.

I would like to focus my question to ask if there is any good source of reference on algorithms (especially computational efficiency thereof) for computing real irreps from complex irreps for finite groups.

Comment: Why has this question got three downvotes?

Comment: The first question in 1 seems to be yes by definition. The answer to 4 is no. For 2 and 3, just replace each complex entry in a matrix by a $2 \times 2$ real entry. The algorithmic question in 1 is more complicated - related algorithms are generally formulated over number fields.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you so much for your kind reply! For 2 and 3, I will think more why such realization is irreducible and how are they related to the number of real irreps vs complex irreps. For 1, could you point me to any reference for algorithms? I'm also looking into GAP.